# Cant find where to get Spring xml namespace entries

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am learning the spring framework and reading spring in action. There are all these namespace entries on the top of the applicationcontext file. Where can i get all these entries for the right version of the spring I am using. I am using the spring release 3.2.4 . Isn't there a resourceful go-to place where I can copy paste from all this tedious and boilerplate xml?
If not, can you provide the entries? I will be learning corespring, mvc, spring-security,  Resttemplate, jdbc, etc..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An XML namespace is just a label to identify XML elements. What you are looking for is the schemas, the XSD files. These are available [here](http://www.springframework.org/schema/).

You would typically have

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    ...

</beans>
```

You'll need a namespace, ex. `xmlns:yours="label"`, and an entry in `schemaLocation` for each additional schema you want to use.

You have to add namespace declarations manually or copy them from some sample. For example, `<mvc:annotation-driven>` is in the `mvc` namespace (check it in my link). The XSD (google that term) describes what the `annotation-driven` and other elements in that namespace can do (what attributes or sub elements they take). If you wanted to use, you'd have to change what you have above to

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

...

</beans>
```

In other words you declared another namespace that describes your XML content. Note that the `xmlns:mvc` attribute value has nothing to do with the location of the schema. It is just convention to have a URL. The schema location must point to a valid XSD.

Comment: Okay. But where do I get the entry to put on top of the file? I can't type out what is written in the book, that will take me for ever.

Comment: Please explain, the answer you gave just confused me further. How do I go about adding namespaces in the xml file? Why is     <mvc:annotation-driven/> not working??

Comment: @user2081579 See the additional details in my edited answer. You'll basically have to either write it yourself, copy it from some sample, or use an IDE to generate it for you.